# Merging javadocs from multiple projects in Hudson

Tags: hudson, javadoc

I have a Hudson job for an x number of extension projects. I say X because the number might vary over time and I would like to avoid creating one job for each.

I already set up a job and I'm able to compile, test, generate javadocs and PMD analysis for all of them. Hudson is able merge everything but I would like to merge javadocs as well.

Basically the project structure is as follows:

```
ProjectAExtension
ProjectBExtension
.
.
.
ProjectNExtension
extension-build.xml
```

I use the Extension within the folder name to iterate thru the folders. Any idea in how to merge the javadocs into one (there are no links between the projects)?

Answer (score 0):

The best way so far is having all the projects set up in Maven as a parent child relationship. The Maven plug-ins take care of the rest.